# How To Correctly Display A Dialog Box During Long Processing - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Running into a situation when user searches for orders of customer for past 4 years. As the DB query takes a long time, I want to show a pop up box just stating 'please wait. quering for results'.  so when they start their search I want to show the message box until the results are obtainned and at that point I want to close the message box.

My current way, I know is incorrect as the pop up box locks up and states (not responding).
Would using a background worker be an over kill, or should I go with a progress bar?

My current way:

```
  Dim frmProcessing As New ShowWaitForm
'/ set location to open the form
'/ set any custom message
frmProcessing.Show()

'//do db query and other stuff with result-> i CANNOT CHANGE THIS CALL NOR CAN I MODIFY HOW IT IS CALLED/FUNCTIONS

frmProcessing.Close()
frmProcessing = Nothing
```

Comment: A progress bar wouldn't work either because it would still be running on the same thread as the task. If you want to do any UI updates then you'll need to look into some concurrent solution such as threading or the background worker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally find the background worker to be a better choice most of the time.  It allows me some more flexibility later if I want to add more information.  I can use the ProgressChanged event to update a progress bar, and later if my needs change I can do other things as well.